# Parsing comments in yaml-cpp

Tags: parsing, comments, yaml, yaml-cpp

as a part of a bigger project i create a graphical yaml-file editor in c++ (and Qt). I use the yaml-cpp library and everything works fine.
Ist it possible to parse comments, too? Writing comments is no problem, but i did not find a solution to read them.

Thanks in advance,
Filip

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible (comments are not part of the representation graph, so they're not retained).

Comment: damn, too bad. It is possible in xml. Any workaround ideas or do i have to parse the files myself?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could just add them as part of the data:

```
# This is an example yaml config file
_comment: This is a comment I would like to retain with my data
foo:
   _comment: Another one
   bar: 1
   baz: '2'
fie:
   bar: 3
   baz: "4"
fum:
   bar: 5
   baz: 6
```